# mod_jk and mod_rewrite with prefix

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, forward, mod-jk

We are trying to configure apache to forward requests to different servers hosting different Application servers.

We want to achieve the following.

```
www.mydomain.com/server1 --->forward to ---> 172.30.34.50:8082 (AP1 jboss)
www.mydomain.com/server2 --->forward to ---> 172.30.34.51:8082  (AP2 jboss)
```

Our current configuration:

mod_jk.conf:

```
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
```

httpd.conf

```
JkMount /cliente1* ajp13unsecure

RewriteEngine on   
RewriteLog logs/apache-mod_rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteRule ^/cliente1(/)?([^/]*)/?$ /$2 [L,PT]  (tried w/o PT with no success)
```

The problem is that when `mod_jk` forwards the request, it gets to the application servers like this: `172.30.34.50:8082/server1`

Which is not a valid resource in the application server, it should go to root (`172.30.34.50:8082`)

We tried using `mod_rewrite`, but it triggers before `mod_jk`, so when apache try to match `mod_jk` rule, it doesn't satisfy the condition anymore. And the request is not forwarded.

How can we get `mod_rewrite` to trigger right before `mod_jk` does the forwarding so the application servers get the correct URI.

Or is there a way to configure `mod_jk` to forward request without the context?

Answer (score 1):

> How can we get `mod_rewrite` to trigger right before `mod_jk` does the
>   forwarding so the application servers get the correct URI.

Not too sure why I have noticed an uptick in people asking about `mod_jk`, but in my experience `mod_proxy` works better & is easier to understand for doing what you are attempting to do.

To enable `mod_proxy` in Apache do the following; assuming you are on Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

Then restart Apache like this; again assuming you are on Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That done, this is a simple setup that should work within your Apache config. Winging it based on your settings:

```
# Settings for adding a trailing slash to the URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(server1|server2)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/ [R=301,L]

# Settings for Apache Reverse Proxying
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

  # Proxy specific settings
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /server1 http://172.30.34.50:8082/
  ProxyPassReverse /server1 http://172.30.34.50:8082/

  ProxyPass /server2 http://172.30.34.51:8082/
  ProxyPassReverse /server2 http://172.30.34.51:8082/

</IfModule>
```

The initial `mod_rewrite` settings add a trailing slash to URLs which I found I needed to do in cases where a path fragment—like `/server1` and `/server2`—were going through a reverse proxy.

Also note I have `/server1` and `/server2` set but they might need to have a slash added to them like this `/server1/` and this `/server2/`. Experiment to see what works best.

Comment: is it possible to configure mod_proxy to expose SSL information to web application? because we are using https too( currently with mod_jk using AJPs). thanks a lot for the prompt response.